# Cannot borrow `scores` as mutable more than once?

Tags: rust, hashmap, borrow-checker

An exercise gives me football matches, with teams and their scores (like: "England,France,4,2"), and I have to insert the teams in a hashmap with its goals scored and conceded. The key is the name of the team and I pass the goals scored and conceded as a struct.

The exercise then gives me another string with a team already in the hashmap ("England,Spain,1,3") and I have to update the hashmap on the England key, adding the goals from that match. How can I do that?

My code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1465777a992226d8ad6c3b0e4b983577)):

```rust
// hashmaps3.rs

// A list of scores (one per line) of a soccer match is given. Each line
// is of the form :
// <team_1_name>,<team_2_name>,<team_1_goals>,<team_2_goals>
// Example: England,France,4,2 (England scored 4 goals, France 2).

// You have to build a scores table containing the name of the team, goals
// the team scored, and goals the team conceded. One approach to build
// the scores table is to use a Hashmap. The solution is partially
// written to use a Hashmap, complete it to pass the test.

// Make me pass the tests!

// Execute `rustlings hint hashmaps3` or use the `hint` watch subcommand for a hint.

// I AM NOT DONE

use std::collections::HashMap;

// A structure to store team name and its goal details.
struct Team {
    name: String,
    goals_scored: u8,
    goals_conceded: u8,
}

fn build_scores_table(results: String) -> HashMap<String, Team> {
    // The name of the team is the key and its associated struct is the value.
    let mut scores: HashMap<String, Team> = HashMap::new();

    for r in results.lines() {
        let v: Vec<&str> = r.split(',').collect();
        let team_1_name = v[0].to_string();
        let team_1_score: u8 = v[2].parse().unwrap();
        let team_2_name = v[1].to_string();
        let team_2_score: u8 = v[3].parse().unwrap();
        let team_1 = Team {
            name: team_1_name.clone(),
            goals_scored: team_1_score,
            goals_conceded: team_2_score,
        };
        let team_2 = Team {
            name: team_2_name.clone(),
            goals_scored: team_2_score,
            goals_conceded: team_1_score,
        };
        let team1 = scores.entry(team_1_name).or_insert(team_1);
        let team2 = scores.entry(team_2_name).or_insert(team_2);
        team1.goals_scored += team_1_score;
        team1.goals_conceded += team_2_score;
        team2.goals_scored += team_2_score;
        team2.goals_conceded += team_1_score;
    }
    scores
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    fn get_results() -> String {
        let results = "".to_string()
            + "England,France,4,2\n"
            + "France,Italy,3,1\n"
            + "Poland,Spain,2,0\n"
            + "Germany,England,2,1\n";
        results
    }

    #[test]
    fn build_scores() {
        let scores = build_scores_table(get_results());

        let mut keys: Vec<&String> = scores.keys().collect();
        keys.sort();
        assert_eq!(
            keys,
            vec!["England", "France", "Germany", "Italy", "Poland", "Spain"]
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn validate_team_score_1() {
        let scores = build_scores_table(get_results());
        let team = scores.get("England").unwrap();
        assert_eq!(team.goals_scored, 5);
        assert_eq!(team.goals_conceded, 4);
    }

    #[test]
    fn validate_team_score_2() {
        let scores = build_scores_table(get_results());
        let team = scores.get("Spain").unwrap();
        assert_eq!(team.goals_scored, 0);
        assert_eq!(team.goals_conceded, 2);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `scores` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:49:21
   |
48 |         let team1 = scores.entry(team_1_name).or_insert(team_1);
   |                     ------------------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
49 |         let team2 = scores.entry(team_2_name).or_insert(team_2);
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
50 |         team1.goals_scored += team_1_score;
   |         ---------------------------------- first borrow later used here
```

I think I understand the error, so I have tried using
`let team1 = &mut scores.entry...`. That is spitting some weird errors. So I am lost here, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This [seems to work on the playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a240fc2653fb86d292d1115c6bef39bb) Could you add more information (e.g. the complete error message)?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Borrow two mutable values from the same HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47773849/155423); [How can I mutate other elements of a HashMap when using the entry pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52846885/155423); and a number of others.  If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Doesn't your code count goals twice if `or_insert` inserted them into the map?

Comment: For fixing your code: don't use both `entry` values simultaneously. Instead, query the first one, set its values, then query the second one. You can't borrow from a map twice mutably at the same time.

Comment: Thanks @Finomnis, it did solved the error. It was still failing the third test, but changing the initial scores to 0, passed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't borrow twice mutable from the same `HashMap`. The `entry()` call borrows from `HashMap`.

To fix this, just don't do it simultaneously. Borrow one, mutate, and then borrow the other.

```rust
// hashmaps3.rs

// A list of scores (one per line) of a soccer match is given. Each line
// is of the form :
// <team_1_name>,<team_2_name>,<team_1_goals>,<team_2_goals>
// Example: England,France,4,2 (England scored 4 goals, France 2).

// You have to build a scores table containing the name of the team, goals
// the team scored, and goals the team conceded. One approach to build
// the scores table is to use a Hashmap. The solution is partially
// written to use a Hashmap, complete it to pass the test.

// Make me pass the tests!

// Execute `rustlings hint hashmaps3` or use the `hint` watch subcommand for a hint.

// I AM NOT DONE

use std::collections::HashMap;

// A structure to store team name and its goal details.
struct Team {
    name: String,
    goals_scored: u8,
    goals_conceded: u8,
}

fn build_scores_table(results: String) -> HashMap<String, Team> {
    // The name of the team is the key and its associated struct is the value.
    let mut scores: HashMap<String, Team> = HashMap::new();

    for r in results.lines() {
        let v: Vec<&str> = r.split(',').collect();
        let team_1_name = v[0].to_string();
        let team_1_score: u8 = v[2].parse().unwrap();
        let team_2_name = v[1].to_string();
        let team_2_score: u8 = v[3].parse().unwrap();
        let team_1 = Team {
            name: team_1_name.clone(),
            goals_scored: team_1_score,
            goals_conceded: team_2_score,
        };
        let team_2 = Team {
            name: team_2_name.clone(),
            goals_scored: team_2_score,
            goals_conceded: team_1_score,
        };
        let team1 = scores.entry(team_1_name).or_insert(team_1);
        team1.goals_scored += team_1_score;
        team1.goals_conceded += team_2_score;

        let team2 = scores.entry(team_2_name).or_insert(team_2);
        team2.goals_scored += team_2_score;
        team2.goals_conceded += team_1_score;
    }
    scores
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    fn get_results() -> String {
        let results = "".to_string()
            + "England,France,4,2\n"
            + "France,Italy,3,1\n"
            + "Poland,Spain,2,0\n"
            + "Germany,England,2,1\n";
        results
    }

    #[test]
    fn build_scores() {
        let scores = build_scores_table(get_results());

        let mut keys: Vec<&String> = scores.keys().collect();
        keys.sort();
        assert_eq!(
            keys,
            vec!["England", "France", "Germany", "Italy", "Poland", "Spain"]
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn validate_team_score_1() {
        let scores = build_scores_table(get_results());
        let team = scores.get("England").unwrap();
        assert_eq!(team.goals_scored, 5);
        assert_eq!(team.goals_conceded, 4);
    }

    #[test]
    fn validate_team_score_2() {
        let scores = build_scores_table(get_results());
        let team = scores.get("Spain").unwrap();
        assert_eq!(team.goals_scored, 0);
        assert_eq!(team.goals_conceded, 2);
    }
}
```

That said, there are still problems with your code. Mainly that you write the goals to the team at `or_insert()`, and then add them again.

If you insert, insert with an empty score, as you will add the goals later.

```rust
// hashmaps3.rs

// A list of scores (one per line) of a soccer match is given. Each line
// is of the form :
// <team_1_name>,<team_2_name>,<team_1_goals>,<team_2_goals>
// Example: England,France,4,2 (England scored 4 goals, France 2).

// You have to build a scores table containing the name of the team, goals
// the team scored, and goals the team conceded. One approach to build
// the scores table is to use a Hashmap. The solution is partially
// written to use a Hashmap, complete it to pass the test.

// Make me pass the tests!

// Execute `rustlings hint hashmaps3` or use the `hint` watch subcommand for a hint.

// I AM NOT DONE

use std::collections::HashMap;

// A structure to store team name and its goal details.
struct Team {
    name: String,
    goals_scored: u8,
    goals_conceded: u8,
}

fn build_scores_table(results: String) -> HashMap<String, Team> {
    // The name of the team is the key and its associated struct is the value.
    let mut scores: HashMap<String, Team> = HashMap::new();

    for r in results.lines() {
        let v: Vec<&str> = r.split(',').collect();
        let team_1_name = v[0].to_string();
        let team_1_score: u8 = v[2].parse().unwrap();
        let team_2_name = v[1].to_string();
        let team_2_score: u8 = v[3].parse().unwrap();
        let team_1 = Team {
            name: team_1_name.clone(),
            goals_scored: 0,
            goals_conceded: 0,
        };
        let team_2 = Team {
            name: team_2_name.clone(),
            goals_scored: 0,
            goals_conceded: 0,
        };
        let team1 = scores.entry(team_1_name).or_insert(team_1);
        team1.goals_scored += team_1_score;
        team1.goals_conceded += team_2_score;

        let team2 = scores.entry(team_2_name).or_insert(team_2);
        team2.goals_scored += team_2_score;
        team2.goals_conceded += team_1_score;
    }
    scores
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    fn get_results() -> String {
        let results = "".to_string()
            + "England,France,4,2\n"
            + "France,Italy,3,1\n"
            + "Poland,Spain,2,0\n"
            + "Germany,England,2,1\n";
        results
    }

    #[test]
    fn build_scores() {
        let scores = build_scores_table(get_results());

        let mut keys: Vec<&String> = scores.keys().collect();
        keys.sort();
        assert_eq!(
            keys,
            vec!["England", "France", "Germany", "Italy", "Poland", "Spain"]
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn validate_team_score_1() {
        let scores = build_scores_table(get_results());
        let team = scores.get("England").unwrap();
        assert_eq!(team.goals_scored, 5);
        assert_eq!(team.goals_conceded, 4);
    }

    #[test]
    fn validate_team_score_2() {
        let scores = build_scores_table(get_results());
        let team = scores.get("Spain").unwrap();
        assert_eq!(team.goals_scored, 0);
        assert_eq!(team.goals_conceded, 2);
    }
}
```

Further, you can extract the creation of a new team with empty scores into a separate function. This makes your code a lot cleaner. Further, you can use `.or_insert_with()` to run the initialization code only when needed.

```rust
// hashmaps3.rs

// A list of scores (one per line) of a soccer match is given. Each line
// is of the form :
// <team_1_name>,<team_2_name>,<team_1_goals>,<team_2_goals>
// Example: England,France,4,2 (England scored 4 goals, France 2).

// You have to build a scores table containing the name of the team, goals
// the team scored, and goals the team conceded. One approach to build
// the scores table is to use a Hashmap. The solution is partially
// written to use a Hashmap, complete it to pass the test.

// Make me pass the tests!

// Execute `rustlings hint hashmaps3` or use the `hint` watch subcommand for a hint.

// I AM NOT DONE

use std::collections::HashMap;

// A structure to store team name and its goal details.
struct Team {
    name: String,
    goals_scored: u8,
    goals_conceded: u8,
}

impl Team {
    fn new(name: &str) -> Self {
        Self {
            name: name.to_string(),
            goals_scored: 0,
            goals_conceded: 0,
        }
    }
}

fn build_scores_table(results: String) -> HashMap<String, Team> {
    // The name of the team is the key and its associated struct is the value.
    let mut scores: HashMap<String, Team> = HashMap::new();

    for r in results.lines() {
        let v: Vec<&str> = r.split(',').collect();
        let team_1_name = v[0].to_string();
        let team_1_score: u8 = v[2].parse().unwrap();
        let team_2_name = v[1].to_string();
        let team_2_score: u8 = v[3].parse().unwrap();

        let team1 = scores
            .entry(team_1_name.clone())
            .or_insert_with(|| Team::new(&team_1_name));
        team1.goals_scored += team_1_score;
        team1.goals_conceded += team_2_score;

        let team2 = scores
            .entry(team_2_name.clone())
            .or_insert_with(|| Team::new(&team_2_name));
        team2.goals_scored += team_2_score;
        team2.goals_conceded += team_1_score;
    }
    scores
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    fn get_results() -> String {
        let results = "".to_string()
            + "England,France,4,2\n"
            + "France,Italy,3,1\n"
            + "Poland,Spain,2,0\n"
            + "Germany,England,2,1\n";
        results
    }

    #[test]
    fn build_scores() {
        let scores = build_scores_table(get_results());

        let mut keys: Vec<&String> = scores.keys().collect();
        keys.sort();
        assert_eq!(
            keys,
            vec!["England", "France", "Germany", "Italy", "Poland", "Spain"]
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn validate_team_score_1() {
        let scores = build_scores_table(get_results());
        let team = scores.get("England").unwrap();
        assert_eq!(team.goals_scored, 5);
        assert_eq!(team.goals_conceded, 4);
    }

    #[test]
    fn validate_team_score_2() {
        let scores = build_scores_table(get_results());
        let team = scores.get("Spain").unwrap();
        assert_eq!(team.goals_scored, 0);
        assert_eq!(team.goals_conceded, 2);
    }
}
```